# What are the mandatory requirements of 100 % SaaS web UI?

Tags: web, saas, rbac, multi-tenant

Apart from RBAC, Multi-Tenancy and Subscription, are any other parameters  required mandatorily for 100% SaaS web UI?

Comment: How is RBAC mandatory? Many apps do not have RBAC... Gmail for one

Comment: @DavidBrossard, please refer Amazon's IAM, it is completely policy driven per customer and its users. Great deal of development going on there

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a couple more

1. White labelling [Branding, skinning of pages and logo's per customer]
2. Custom settings for various application features
3. Custom UI layouts at the highest level of customization part in the UI front
4. Custom login screens, the most desired feature
5. Custom date, date-time formatting and globalization
6. Custom data lables
7. Fine grained security controlling who sees what in the UI based on your RBAC

Just a few points that I wished could share with you